# footruleskip already defined error when remove header line - abntex

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, abnt

I'm trying to remove the line of the header. Doing some searches, the best answer was `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` but when I add the package `fancyhdr` I get an error saying that the footruleskip command is already defined.

I'm using `\pagestyle{myheadings}` to remove the Chapter title from the header.

```
\include{fixos/instituicao/sistemas}
%\linespread{1.5}
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries}{\thesection\space }{12pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{\rmdefault}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\begin{document}
.
.
.
```

the template that Im using https://github.com/guylhermetabosa/TCC/tree/master/modelo-tcc-abntex2 **TCC.tex is the main file**
[image]

Comment: `abntex2` uses `memoir` under the hood and it uses its own mechanism for headers and footers and is incompatible with `fancyhdr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repository shown seems to be a university template. Documented code is in a language i don't speak, but doing the regular algorithm of making a minimal working example, it boils down to `/textual` which is the mainmatter in `abntex2`. The pagestyle is set to `abntheadings` along with
`\makeheadrule{abntheadings}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}`. We can see, that the key is to make the width of that line equal to zero point, i.e. having an invisible rule.

```
\documentclass{abntex2}
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\renewcommand{\normalrulethickness}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\textual
\chapter{lambada leguan}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

---

As this is a university template adhering to the ABNT, it might not be a good idea to redefine their layout of pages. `memoir` internally uses `normalrulethickness` in various occasions, so redefining it might lead to unexpected outcome.

---

**EDIT:** Instead of changing the `\normalrulethickness`, it is possible to modify the `abntheadings` style: `\makeheadrule{abntheadings}{\textwidth}{0pt}` in the preamble, by doing so only the `abntex2` heading is changed. (Guilherme Z. Santos)

Comment: Care to elaborate/explain? This isn't a very good answer at the moment IMHO.

Comment: @PaulGessler Because i don't understand any of the stuff that is going on in that template. There is a lot of crazy stuff going on, but it all boils down to setting the `normalrulethickness`.

Comment: @Johannes_B that comment is already more of an explanation than the answer gave... why not just put it in the answer?

Comment: Give me a  moment @paul :-)

Comment: I don't like this template, I'm going crazy. But I've to use it

Comment: @paul done updating :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B -- `memoir` also used `\normalrulethickness` in `\setfootnoterule`, so this will likely have an unintended side effect.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Possible. But since this is a university template adhering to the ABNT standards, i think removing that line in the first place i a very bad idea. Maybe i should add my concerns to the answer.

Comment: @Johannes_B -- good idea.  that's really all i was trying to suggest.

Comment: Johannes_B,barbara-beeton, paul-gessler I also don't want to remove the line, because it's the abnt template, but, my college asked me to do this, I don't agree, but... I can just accept. This and other requests to change the template gave me a lot of work and problems

Comment: @ItaloPessoa -- if the university can't or won't accept the output from using this template/document class without the kinds of adjustments they're requesting, then it is not an appropriate tool for the job.  this should be taken up with the university authorities.  i'm not suggesting that *you* should undertake this, but if you could make clear to someone with "connections" that it is causing unnecessary difficulties *unrelated to reporting your research*, then maybe someone else in the future could benefit.  (and good luck.  i hope everything else goes well.)

Comment: @ItaloPessoa Or in other words, it makes absolutely no sense to request a template, and make *every* student make the same changes. It is an insane amount of work that could be avoided or put to better benefits.